# Pymongo gives db assertion failure while trying to access remote server

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am getting the following error:

> db assertion failure, assertion: 'unauthorized db:db1 lock type:-1 client:', assertionCode: 10057

I am able to access the MongoDB database by running python on the shell of my server. But when I try to access my site i get this unauthorised errors.

Any fix for this error?

Answer (score 5):

This means that your database is using authentication. In such a setup, you must authenticate a valid user before you can perform any operations (queries, commands, updates, etc). You can do so with the `db.auth(username, password)` helper in the mongo shell ([described in the MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-ConfiguringAuthenticationandSecurity)), and with Python, you can use the `authenticate(username, password)` method of the `Database` object ([described in the PyMongo docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate))

Comment: i am trying that now...but isnt this authentication required when i am accessing the database from my shell coz i am able to do that without authentication

Comment: There's a bug in PyMongo right now where each thread needs to re-authenticate, since the authentication credentials are not cached in the driver. This bug should be fixed in 1.12.

Comment: k..thnx  a lot and when is that due

Comment: You can follow the progress of pymongo releases here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON